# insert large data from txt to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, text, insert, large-data

A simple question: Any ideas on how to import nearly 5M email addresses from a text file to a mysql DB using php quickly? My script is working well, but it is running for 90 hrs now and it inserted only 700.000 entries. Sadly I did not realize until now that I have 5M lines in my txt file. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand how you can only insert 700,000 records in **90** hours. There is something not quite right here

Comment: I do check the existing entries for each new line(new email address) to avoid inserting duplicate data.

Comment: and also the insertion is made into a remote mysql server. Do you think that inserting into a local mysql would speed up this much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't just use the "load data infile" function that mysql provides if the file is already on your server.

[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

> The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed.

As for uniqueness, why don't you just add the UNIQUE constraint to your mysql table? That way you don't need to check for unique constraints?

I haven't tried this myself but I would try do it like that.

Comment: I`ll check it now and leave a reply here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: added ignore, now it runs. I`ll check te results in a few mins

Comment: It inserted only 34 rows :(. There may be a problem with the newline characters and the end of each email in the txt file? I don`t have any idea...

Comment: Oh... Yeah... I think there is a way to tell it that a new line character is the terminating character. Did you enter something like `LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE table2
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\n";` Is it a line termination problem? **Edit:** Also consider doing a small test locally before sending it to the server. Use about 1000 lines.